# Can we insert elements into a linked list using for-loop in python?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, linked-list, insert, singly-linked-list

I implemented a singly linked list like

```
class LinkList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None 

class Node:
     def __init__(self, val=0):
        self.val = val
        self.next = None
```

```
a = [2, 5, 6, 3, 5, 6, 9]
```

I was wondering if we can insert each element of the above list using a `for`-loop into the linked list.

I tried to do so, but it is not adding all values to the list. Here is my attempt:

```
a = [2, 5, 6, 3, 5, 6, 9]
l.head = Node(a[0])
l.head.next = Node(a[1])
for i in range(1, len(a) - 1):
    Node(a[i]).next = Node(a[i + 1])
```

When after running this, I print the linked list, it only outputs:

```
2
5
```

How can this be done right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `for` loop. I will first present how I would do that.

First improve the `Node` constructor so that you can pass a value for its `next` property:

```
class Node:
     def __init__(self, val=0, nxt=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = nxt
```

So this makes no difference if you don't pass that extra argument, but it can be useful sometimes to pass that argument also.

Then improve the constructor of the `LinkList` class so that optionally you can pass a sequence of values (e.g. as a list). Then the constructor can do the looping. It is quite elegant (I think) to loop over the given sequence in reversed order, so that you *prepend* values to the list:

```
class LinkList:
    def __init__(self, seq=None):
        self.head = None 
        if seq is not None:
            for val in reversed(seq):
                self.head = Node(val, self.head)
```

And now you can create your linked list from a list in a one liner:

```
l = LinkList([2, 5, 6, 3, 5, 6, 9])
```

As to your attempt. The assignment you do in the loop body, is to a *new* node each time, not to the previously added node. So your nodes do not chain all together. In each iteration you create *two* nodes where the first links with the second, but that pair remains disconnected from anything else.

Instead you should retain a reference to the previously created node and use it in the next iteration of the loop. Obviously one iteration of the loop should only create one Node instance, and have it linked from the reference you retained.

Here is the fix to your attempt:

```
l = LinkList()
a = [2, 5, 6, 3, 5, 6, 9]
node = Node(a[0])
l.head = node
for val in a[1:]:
    node.next = Node(val)
    node = node.next
```

Comment: Thank you for the easy explanation and quick answer sir!

Comment: Hello Sir! Is it okay to ask another related question in this comment section?

Comment: The comment section is mainly for getting clarifications or pointing to problems with the answer. If you have a follow up question, then ask it as a new question. You can always have it refer to your previous question so people see the connection.

Comment: Thank you so much sir!